# Why IPhone Phonegap application renders css differently than native browser?

Tags: iphone, browser, cordova

I am creating an PhoneGap application for iPhone. 
When I am designing and testing HTML file in PC-Browser it looks different.
And In Phone gap it looks different. 
Actually CSS not functioning as accepted. Is this known issue? OR Am I missing something?
I can provide code snippet or screen-shots if needed. Please help

Comment: posting the included files in `index.html` might help...

Comment: What browser are you using on PC?

Comment: Safari/Chrome/Firefox ---All browsers I tried to get the results...

Comment: did u add <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1; user-scalable=no;">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing code this is almost impossible to actually answer. BUT I will say this - with mobile you are using Webkit, meaning that anything in your CSS that referes to -moz- will not work. Also, you're dealing with a version of webkit, not the newest, and not the oldest - well that is unless your on android 2.2.2

You should be safe to use any -webkit- syntax in your CSS, but just know that certain properties may not be supported in android as they have fragmented their phones quite and bit and have shipped a somewhat old version of webkit with specific OS's.

iPhone you should be all good to go, now if you continue to have issues that are more specific I would recommend you post your code so we can see what is going on - you could just have some weird markup somewhere.